# Return OAuth Token information on user creation endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently implementing a REST Api using Spring Boot and secured via OAuth2. This is my current situation:

1. User registration endpoint, a sample success response and the controller method implementation

`POST http://<host>/users/register`

```
{
  "id": "6061b5c0-a817-4fff-ba1f-c7f4e94080ed",
  "name": "Name",
  "email": "user@email.com",
  "password": "$2a$12$R7yw/HbLmFzMpkzsWOqLp.I.itHRo7B/9MXKNrpArvK/Lfta0Z.I.",
  "createdAt": "2019-12-14T22:00:46.682+0000"
  ...
}
```

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody final User user) {
    final User createdUser = mUsersService.create(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

2. The token endpoint and a sample response

`POST http://<host>/oauth/token`

```
{
  "access_token": "03bd76f0-20bd-45ef-9adb-b0903345e590",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "a1022bbd-407a-4899-b1b0-20a889ed0419",
  "expires_in": 82373,
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

How can I return the token JSON (as returned by the `/oauth/token` endpoint) on the `/users/register` endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after inspecting the data that goes into the `/oauth/token` endpoint, I came to the following solution:

```
    private static final String PARAM_GRANT_TYPE = "grant_type";
    private static final String PARAM_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PARAM_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String PARAM_GRANT_TYPE_VALUE_PASSWORD = "password";

    @Autowired
    private UsersService mUsersService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenEndpoint mTokenEndpoint;

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> register(final Principal principal,
                                                      @RequestParam final String name,
                                                      @RequestParam final String email,
                                                      @RequestParam final String password) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
        final User user = mUsersService.create(name, email, password);

        final Map<String, String> tokenParameters = new HashMap<>(3);
        tokenParameters.put(PARAM_GRANT_TYPE, PARAM_GRANT_TYPE_VALUE_PASSWORD);
        tokenParameters.put(PARAM_USERNAME, email);
        tokenParameters.put(PARAM_PASSWORD, password);

        return mTokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(principal, tokenParameters);
    }
```

What I do is invoke the POST token endpoint with the forwarded Principal (in my case the client authentication) and the normal `password` `grant_type` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method,

```
private OAuth2AccessToken getToken(LoginResource loginResource) {
    String access_token_url = "http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token";
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(access_token_url);

    //-- set the clients info
    resourceDetails.setClientId("clientId");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("clientSecret");

    // set scopes
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add("read"); 
    scopes.add("write");
    scopes.add("trust");
    resourceDetails.setScope(scopes);

    //-- set Resource Owner info
    resourceDetails.setUsername(loginResource.getUserName());
    resourceDetails.setPassword(loginResource.getPassword());
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
    return oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(); 
}
```